# Compare cell 1 with cell 2 in the same column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need some help with this in SQL. 
I have a query like this

```
select sub.*
from(
    select 
        distinct columnA,   
        case
            when length ("columnA") > 16 then 'Org_ID'
            when length ("columnA") <= 16 then 'non_Org_ID'
        end as ColumnC,
        columnB,    
        "ColumnD"
    from Table1
    where "ColumnD"::date = '2018-08-31 00:00:00'::date
    UNION
    select 
        distinct columnA,   
        case
            when length ("columnA") > 16 then 'Org_ID'
            when length ("columnA") <= 16 then 'non_Org_ID'
        end as ColumnC,
        columnB,    
        "ColumnD"
    from Table1
    where "ColumnD"::date = '2019-07-01 00:00:00'::date
    ) sub
order by sub.columnC

                 Result
   Column A  Column B  Column C  Column D  
       1                  a 
       1                  a
       2                  b
       3                  b
       4                  c
       4                  d
```

Now to that Result I need to apply a logic like this. If in column C cell 1 equal to Cell 2, and in column A cell 1 equal cell 2 then 'True' else 'false', and move to next cell. The result needed is something like this

```
 Column A  Column B  Column C  Column D  Column E
       1                  a                True
       1                  a                (blanks)
       2                  b                False 
       3                  b                (blanks)
       4                  c                True
       4                  d                (blanks)
```

The blanks are not 100% necessary.

Thanks

Comment: _"identify when the value in column B have different value in column A"_ What does this mean? Share your query please, `True/False` according to what?

Comment: Hi, well. If in column B  cell 1 equal to Cell 2, and in column A cell 1 equal cell 2 then 'True' else 'false'.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `true` when the values are all the same and `false` otherwise.  Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(a) over (partition by b) = max(a) over (partition by b)
             then 'true' else 'false'
        end) as flag
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=759440dcedfb2b8a7dd099c82cb2490f) is a db<>fiddle showing that it works.

Comment: Yes basically is the idea. I'm using that statment but receiving true in all the rows, which is not correct. 

"case 
        when min(customer_id) over(partition by collector_id) = max(customer_id) 
         over(partition by collector_id) then 'True' else 'False' end as flag"

Comment: @CarlosArronteBello . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  It works.

Comment: Thanks, i guess I'm doing something wrong. I will check

Answer (score 1):

You can `group by columna, columnb` to get the rows that are the same and join to the table:

```
select t.*,
  case g.counter when 1 then 'False' else 'True' end columnc 
from tablename t inner join (
  select columna, columnb, count(*) counter
  from tablename 
  group by columna, columnb  
)g on g.columna = t.columna and g.columnb = t.columnb
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c3c58c72eb359fa78d35f016ec149067).
Results:

```
> columna | columnb | columnc
> ------: | :------ | :------
>       1 | a       | True   
>       1 | a       | True   
>       2 | b       | False  
>       3 | b       | False  
>       4 | c       | True   
>       4 | c       | True
```

Comment: That looks pretty good, but no 100% sure how to implement this with the query  I already have. Can i share you my query via email ?

Comment: I don't share email. The code in this answer is related to the question as you posted it.